# Powerfit not fitting to the empirical data

Tags: python, power-law

I am trying to fit some data with an powerlaw fit, but the powerlaw starts at the right xmin which is 230, but it always starts at y level = 1 , when it should start at cords = (x,y) = (230,0.3) , What am i doing wrong?
The datasets are from Newman, but why is the redline alwas starting at y = 1?

[image: fitted data]

```
def powerPlot(fit):
    plt.figure()
    fig1 = fit.plot_ccdf(original_data=True, color='blue', linestyle='', marker='o', markersize=10, markerfacecolor='none', label='CCDF')
 
    fit.power_law.plot_ccdf(ax=fig1, survival=True, color='red', linestyle='--', alpha=1)
    fit.truncated_power_law.plot_ccdf(ax=fig1, color='purple', linestyle='--', alpha=1)




import pipe 
import plotsettings as ps
import printValues as pV
import plotDist as pD


def main():

    data = pipe.getData("Black.txt")

    fit = powerlaw.Fit(data) 
    fit2 = powerlaw.Fit(data, xmin = fit.xmin, xmax = fit.xmax , alpha = fit.alpha, discrete = True)
    
    #fit3 = powerlaw.Fit(data, xmin = 1)
    #pV.printAlpha(fit)
    #pV.printXmin(fit)
    #pV.printRAndP(fit)
    #pD.bigPlot(fit2)

   # pV.printBig(fit2)
   # pD.bigPlot(fit)
    pD.powerPlot(fit2)
   # pD.expPlot(fit2)
    #pD.normPlot(fit2)

    ps.setPlot("Words.txt")

main()
```

I tried to make the powerlaw fit to the empirical data, it kinda fits but it starts at the right x level but wrong y level

Comment: Where are these imports coming from? Which packages are you using?

Comment: Note that your data don't follow a power-law, so any fit will be off.

Comment: Non-linear least-squares fitting (which this likely is) becomes tricky when data spans multiple orders of magnitude, in part because of floating point precision errors. If you want to fit a power-law to the data, you'll likely get better results by fitting a linear curve (aka a straight line) in log-log space: convert your data by taking log(y) and log(x) and fit for y = ax + c.

Comment: Im using the powerlaw package and matplotlib

Comment: I know that it doesn't fit a powerlaw at the moment but i have some other datasets that do but get the same problem with the dashed lines always starting at y level 1

Comment: Also the redline is powerlawfit and the purpble is "suposed " to be powerlaw with cutoff"

Comment: I don't know the powerlaw package, but I see imports for pipe, plotsettings, prinvValues and plotDist, none of which are common. On the other hand, `powerlaw` comes out of nowhere in the code.

Comment: non-linear fitting is particularly sensitive to its starting values; it's easy to end up in a local minimum. Have you tried setting the starting parameter values to something that roughly matches the data?

Comment: Yes have tried to "hard code it" to start at the xmin still the same problem